# SSRS line chart. How to stop numbers from repeating in vertical axis

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, business-intelligence, bids

I have a line chart in ssrs. Whenever the highest line values are 1 or 2 instead of getting a scale of 0,1,2 which is what I want, I get 0,1,1,2,2. This dosn't make sense especially because the number values are not decimals and are unformatted.

Please help.

Comment: Can you tell me is it the =count(fields!Item.Value) in the chart that you are using or =Sum(fields!Item.Value) for the value

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Expression for the vertical axis Interval should be below expressions.

If your value is sum

=IIF(Max(Sum(Fields!Item.Value))<20,1,"Auto")

If your value is count

=IIF(Max(Count(Fields!Item.Value))<20,1,"Auto")

Note: I used 20 as the above that the Auto will work good. Make according to your requirement.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like there is formatting on the vertical axis: That it's actually trying to show 0, .5, 1.0, 1.5, & 2 but after rounding that comes out as 0,1,1,2,2

You should change the vertical axis interval from "Auto" to 1:[image]

Comment: I am aware of that. However the values in the database are integers not decimals. and also this chart could have values anywhere from 1 to 100,000, so I really don't want to change the interval property.

Comment: Try a formula such as `=10 ^ LEN( ROUND((MAX(Fields!MyField.Value, "MyDataSetName")))` That it's only integers in the database won't change this: SSRS will still put fractional intervals in.

Answer (score 1):

I understand that this is quite old post. Still I wanted to reply..

I faced the same issue on column chart when the scale was of small range....

So I used the following expression in **axis properties->interval**

**=IIF(Max(Fields!count_Items.Value)>=6,0,1)  - [note: here 0 means - Auto interval]**

Hope this answer helps someone. :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is not only the interval but also the maximum value of the range that the axis uses. You can set the value for the Interval with this type of expression IIF(Max(Sum(Fields!Item.Value))<20,1,"Auto") but the axis can still make the scale too large. It then tends to fill in with decimals or if you suppress decimals you get repeating integers.

Use a custom code like this:

```
Public Shared Function AxisRange(ByVal Number As Double) As String
Dim RangeString as String
If Number <=5 Then 
RangeString ="5" 
Else If Number <=10 Then
RangeString =  "10"
Else RangeString = "Auto" 
End If
Return RangeString
End Function
```

In the Maximum value of the range use an expression like:

=code.AxisRange(Max(Fields!Field.Value))

By doing this you force the maximum value of the range to be a similar size to the maximum value in your chart. This solves the problem.